# How to write a “set-equal?” predicate?

Tags: list, lisp, scheme, set, racket

How do I build a `same?` predicate that returns `#t` with `(same? '(4 6) '(6 4))`?
I'm stuck with writing a `(same? a b)`-predicate that returns `#t` if `a` and `b` are equal sets and `#f` otherwise. Also a similar predicate `(element? el set)` that determines if `el` is a element of `set`.

*(And yes, this is homework so I'm not after a completely finished solution. I just need to get a bump or a few, in the right direction since there's almost no help to be found from our teachers.)*

We are representing sets using lists. We are asked to build everything we need for this our selves. Higher order functions like map etc are pretty much banned.

**The problem is** that my element? and same? doesn't work with:

```
(same? '(4 6) '(6 4))<br/>
(element? '(2 3) '(1 8 5 '(3 2) 4))
```

These should return `#t`, which they don't and I understand why but I still can't fix it.

my `element?` looks like this, and I kind of knew it would only work for lists of the same order but the question is how I can improve it? (`setEmpty`, `setFirst`, `setRest` are defined as `null?`, `car` and `cdr`. We've been asked to make our own for some reason.)

```
(define element?
  (lambda (x set)
     (cond ((setEmpty? set) #f)
      ((equal? x (setFirst set)) #t)
      (else (element? x (setRest set)))
      )
   )
)
```

I have a working `set?`-predicate that looks like this, that might be of use:

```
(define set?
  (lambda (set)
    (cond ((setEmpty? set) #t)
          ((list? (setFirst set))
            (if (element? (setFirst set) (setRest set))
             #f
             (set? (setFirst set))))
          (else (if (element? (setFirst set) (setRest set))
                #f
                (set? (setRest set))
                )
            )
        )
     )
 )
```

This returns `#t` if a list and its "sublists" are without duplicates. I also have a procedure that makes a true set out of a list with duplicates that works fine.

Comment: Just a note:  what you've called "sublists" (in " if a list and its "sublists" are without duplicates.") are sometimes called "tails".  E.g., in Common Lisp, there's a function [`tailp`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_ldiffc.htm) which checks whether an object is a tail of a list.

Comment: That would be useful yes but "higher order"-functions are banned here. What they mean by "higher-order" in this case are pretty much all the functions we have not been using in previous exercises.

Comment: It wouldn't be useful here, since it's a Common Lisp function, not, as far as I know, a Scheme function.  I understand the academic purpose of "don't use the standard libraries", the term "higher-order function" means a function that takes a function as an argument (like `map`) (or possibly a function that returns another function as result).  Anyhow, I wasn't suggesting that you use it;  I was just mentioning that there's already some terminology out there for the concept you were describing.  Being aware of that in the future will help avoid confusion (especially while asking questions). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few pointers, to get you in the right direction.

The `element?` procedure is mostly right, except that it shouldn't use `equal?` for the key comparison - it should use `same?`, and `same?` should differentiate between two cases: whether the elements compared are atoms, or sets.

So it's not hard to imagine that the correctness of the whole exercise depends on the implementation of `same?`. And that in turn, depends on the chosen set representation. There's a whole chapter on [representing sets](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-16.html#%_sec_2.3.3) in the wonderful book SICP (including representing sets as lists), you should start by reading it, to get your bearings.

Once you have implemented the primitive procedures for sets, it's easy to check if two sets are equal, I'll leave it to you to implement `setSize` and `setUnion`:

```
(= (setSize a) (setSize b) (setSize (setUnion a b)))
```

Or alternatively, as pointed by @sds in his answer, you can determine if two sets are the same if they're subsets of each other - and you should implement the `subset?` procedure on your own:

```
(and (subset? a b) (subset? b a))
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Yeah, we actually have sicp as a textbook for this course and I thought I'd read that chapter but probably not thourough enough. Will do! Yes, the problem for me is with same?. I feel I should use same? in element? instead of equal? but at the same time I want to use element? to implement same? =/ ??.

Comment: @remDup no, you should implement `same?` _without_ using `element?`. In `element?` consider two cases: if the parameters are not sets, use `equals?` to test for equality. If they're sets, do any of the comparisons suggested above, and for that you'll have to use the primitive set operations defined.

Comment: Thnx! I think I attacked the problem from the wrong angle from the beginning. Our last assignment was to operate on lists so I think my head was stuck in that. Also we use "pretty-big"-version of racket in which you have to define everything in order which bugs me out =). I will read up more on this in scip and start all over with all your tips in mind. Also, I though both your answers was good but I could only choose one, want to give all of you cred! =).

Comment: ...ps. I think I misunderstood pretty-big a little =). It doesn't seem to work like that at all but I can still re-define let say, a, to be something else further down which i still think is weird for a functional language. Anyway, this is OT so let's not =)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that you are using `equal?` to compare set elements in `element?`.

You need to write your own `element-equal?` which would take into account that set elements may be lists and not atoms and use it instead of `equal?`.

As for `same?` - I think it would be easiest to implement it like this:

```
(define same? 
  (lambda (a b) 
    (and (subset? a b)
         (subset? b a))))
```

and

```
(define subset? 
  (lambda (a b)
    (or (isEmpty a)
        (and (element? (first a) b) 
             (subset? (rest a) b)))))
```

Comment: Thanks a whole lot! We'll see if this helps. I'm signing off for the day. Well I know there's a problem with using equal? there since it wont think of '(3 2) and '(2 3) as the same. I then feel that I should use same? instead of equal? when at the same time I want to use element? when implementing subset? that same? uses. Would'nt that create a problem? ...and yes this is my first proper programming course since a beginner course in java 8 years ago =).

Answer (score 1):

Note for Racket programmers: avoid reinventing the wheel if you can.  If it's appropriate, use the standard library's [`racket/set`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28tech._set%29), which provides a good set implementation.

Comment: Well yes, that would save me alot of trouble. This is an assignment though so all this reinventing is intentional. I guess maybe you knew this and in that case, true, of course. =)

Answer (score 0):

My lab is actually running along smoothly now. I want to thank everyone that made a comment and mention a few things to others struggling with the same kind of implementation.

Pointers from my perspective:
-Think abstractly. Read a quick intro to set theory. Just enough to know the defenitions
of sets, subsets, the empty set, union etc.

-Write down all the procedures on a paper and think about what procedure that needs what other procedure.

-When thinking about how to write same? for example, imagine you have a procedure subset that already works. As a matter of fact, you already have alot of procedures that work, (even though you don't have them yet =) ) don't worry, just try and think what procedures same? would need to make it as neatly as possible. Continue like this for all your procedures.

-You might run in to problems with procedures just sending things back and forth between them and your program goes in to an infinite loop. If you're careful from the beginning and recognize when this prob could arise, you shouldn't run in to it. But occasionally you have to rethink some procedures. Maybe they can use other procedures to accomplish the same thing?

I'll also share a couple of procedures to see what you think. Feel free to butcher them, they work so far =) ..and it's due this friday anyway.
ps. my proc makeSet basically does what it sounds like. It removes all duplicate elements in all "levels".

```
;;; predicate that returns #t if a list is a set and #f otherwise
(define set?
  (lambda (set)
    (cond ((setEmpty? set) #t)
      ((not (list? set)) #f)
      ((equal? (makeSet set) set) #t)
      (else #f))
  )
)

;;; diff returns the difference between set1 and set2
(define diff
  (lambda (set1 set2)
    (cond ((null? set1) '())
       ((null? set2) set1)
       ((not (member? (car set1) set2))
        (cons (car set1) (diff (cdr set1) set2)))
       (else (diff (cdr set1) set2)))
  )
)
```

Oh, and I haven't changed all the car, cdr and cons to our "abstracted" equals setFirst etc, I will. Also I might make diff return a "makeSet-version" of its return value to make sure I always get a set as a return.

Thanks again everyone!
/rem